# How to include the header and the footer of wordpress website to a custom php file?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a custom php file that I want to include the header.php and the footer.php files to it , The file is located inside the theme files next to header.php and footer.php , but when I try

`<?php get_header(); ?>`

I get an error , Undefined function get_header.

Is there is a way to include it or I would have to use include/require to include them manually?

Comment: looks like you trying to access wp functions without loading them. try to use `require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-load.php');` at the top of your custom file. make sure the root for `wp-load.php` is set right for your case

Answer (score 0):

Did you create those files in your project? You should create a `footer.php` and `header.php` on your project.

Your page should look something like so:

```
<!-- The header of the page -->
<?php get_header(); ?>
<!-- The main wrapper of the page -->
<main class="main-container container_960">
    <!-- Main content Section -->
    <section class="main-content">
        <!-- Printing the content -->
        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) :the_post() ?>

            <?php
                    the_title("<h1>","</h1>");

                    the_content();
            ?>

        <?php endwhile; else : ?>
            <!-- Showing that there is no content -->
            <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>

    </section>
    <!-- Pinting the Sidebar -->
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

</main>
<!-- Printing the footer -->
<?php get_footer() ?>
```

Create a file for the header, call it `header.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title><?php  the_title();?></title>
    <!-- This is for adding the meta information, where styles registered in functions php --> 
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>

<header class="the_header">
<!-- You can create your content here
</header>
...
```

And you should create another file for the footer,again `footer.php`:

```
<footer class="main-footer">
        The footer
    </footer>

    <!-- We call here the scripts enqeued in functions.php-->
    <?php wp_footer();?>
</body>
</html>
```